# How do i count 1 or more items in comma separated input in Shell

Tags: shell

Here's my issue, i know how to count the files using the following two strategies but i have a problem with each one.

I am using '.sh' extension.

First:

```
count=`echo $2 | awk -F, {'print NF'}`
```

causes my program to throw an error at me: ***awk: cannot execute - No such file or directory***

Secondly:

```
count=`echo $2 | tr -cd , | wc -c`
```

Works if you have multiple values separated by commas, however, it will not work if the input is a single item with no commas.

Like i said, this was previously working with the awk but for some reason when i ran it on the physical device instead of the virtual machine it gave me that error.

any ideas?

Thing I know are **NOT** the issue:
Version of shell is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `count=$(echo ${2} | awk -F, '{print NF}')` instead - you have your braces and quotes inside-out.

Although, it seems your bigger problem is that `awk` appears to not be executable... You might try `which awk` and `ls -l $(which awk)` to see what's up with that...

Comment: surprizingly, `echo a,b | awk -F, {'print NF'}` worked for me. My guess is a discrep in PATH between "virtual machine and physical device". Good luck to all.
`

Comment: That didn't seem to work as the error is still persisting.  Also there is only one file path that changes but i handle that appropriately elsewhere in the code so that's not the issue.

Comment: As for the `which awk` it returns that there is no awk in :directory

Comment: @tc90 Is your PATH set correctly? Is the `awk` package correctly installed (or maybe `nawk` or `gawk`? What OS is this?

Comment: The OS is QNX; it works with unix based commands as well. And my path is set to !/bin/sh.

I'm not sure how to check if awk or gawk are installed correctly to be honest.  I am pretty new to this and got thrown a huge project at work so I've been learning as I go.

Comment: Just to note when i set the count variable to a static value and run the script everything works correctly so it is simply something wrong with how i'm getting count.

Comment: I figured it out.  After exploring the bin folders i found that awk did not exist, however, gawk did.  I changed the code to look like this: 

    count=`echo $2 | gawk -F, {'print NF'}`

Thank you for the help @twalberg. You pointed me in the right direction!